# One search input keyword and five CheckBoxGroup Filter / Search Keyword Results Filter

Tags: velo

Database Search code works fine. You can see it below. I want to add a checkbox group (5 units) that will integrate with my search code. All run on one database.

How can I add checkboxgroup code that will work with database search code as an example?

```
Column name
Detail ---------- Search input keyword
(the search code works but no filters).....
continent - checkboxgroup1.....
country - checkboxgroup2.....
sector - checkboxgroup3.......
fund - checkboxgroup4......
cvp code - checkboxgroup5
```

My search code

```
import wixData from 'wix-data'; 

export function searchButton_onClick(event) 
{
 //assume the input comes from a component called 'searchInput'
 //CHANGE TO YOUR SPECIFIC COMPONENT NAME
 let searchValue = $w('#SearchBox').value; 

 //split the search inputs into distinct words
 let searchWords = searchValue.split(' '); 

//build a query for 'my-collection'
//CHANGE THIS TO YOUR COLLECTION NAME
let query = wixData.query('Afghanistan')
      .descending("overview");

 //add a "contains" condition to the query for each word:
 //assumes we search in the field 'myField'
 //CHANGE THIS TO YOUR FIELD NAME
 for (let i=0; i < searchWords.length; i++) 
    {       
        query = query.contains('overview', searchWords[i])
    }  

 //actually run the query:
    query.find().then(res => 
    { 
 //give the results to the table to display
 //assume the table is named 'resultsTable' 
 //CHANGE TO YOUR SPECIFIC COMPONENT NAME
        $w('#repeater1').data = res.items; 
    })
    .catch(err =>
    {
        console.log("problem in search! " + err);
    }); 
} 









import wixData from 'wix-data'; 

export function searchButton_onClick(event) 
{
 //assume the input comes from a component called 'searchInput'
 //CHANGE TO YOUR SPECIFIC COMPONENT NAME
 let searchValue = $w('#SearchBox').value; 

 //split the search inputs into distinct words
 let searchWords = searchValue.split(' '); 

 //build a query for 'my-collection'
 //CHANGE THIS TO YOUR COLLECTION NAME
 let query = wixData.query('Afghanistan')
  .descending("overview");

 //add a "contains" condition to the query for each word:
 //assumes we search in the field 'myField'
 //CHANGE THIS TO YOUR FIELD NAME
 for (let i=0; i < searchWords.length; i++) 
    {       
        query = query.contains('overview', searchWords[i])
    }  

 //actually run the query:
    query.find().then(res => 
{ 
 //give the results to the table to display
 //assume the table is named 'resultsTable' 
 //CHANGE TO YOUR SPECIFIC COMPONENT NAME
        $w('#repeater1').data = res.items; 
    })
    .catch(err =>
    {
        console.log("problem in search! " + err);
    }); 
}
```

Below is the working code for filtering. How can I combine two codes.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
filterView();

$w("#checkboxGroup1").onChange( (event, $w) => {
  filterView();
});


$w("#checkboxGroup2").onChange( (event, $w) => {
  //filterView();
//});
});

function filterView(){
    var continentsFilter = $w("#checkboxGroup1").value
    
    var countryFilter = $w("#checkboxGroup2").value
    
    console.log('continents', continentsFilter);
    
    console.log('country', countryFilter);
    
    $w("#dataset1").setFilter( wixData.filter()
    .hasSome("continents", continentsFilter)
    
    .hasSome("country", countryFilter)
    )

    .then( () => {
            let count = $w("#dataset1").getTotalCount(); 
            if(count === 0){
                $w("#group1").show();
            }else{
                $w("#group1").hide();
            }
    } )
    .catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    } );
}
```

Comment: any help would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your search button is running a query and the checkbox group is doing a filter on a dataset. That's usually not a great idea if you want both to work together.

In this case, it seems to me it might be best to just use standard JS to do the filtering when the checkboxes are are clicked. It should also be very fast this way.

The basic idea is to save the data returned from your query before assigning it to your repeater. Then every time there is a change in the checkbox group, you can use the JS `.filter()` function to create a filtered array based off the original query results and the selections in the checkboxes. Use that filtered array to reset the repeater's data.